# Editing a run script build phase in XCode

Tags: iphone, xcode, macos

In XCode I made a new run script build phase and want to do one of two things:

- Edit it
- Delete it

I can see how to add a new one, but not how to access the existing one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In xcode project tree, click on targets, then pick the target for which you added script. Each time you add new script/event it will show up as a new grey folder in target's subtree. Pick folder named 'Run Script', right click, select 'Get info': script body will be in 'General' tab.

If you have multiple scripts, you probably would want to rename them in that target tree.

Comment: thank you! I should really just sit down and read up on the IDE a bit. I've wasted about an hour and a half on really stupid things so far.

Answer (score 6):

I realize this is really old (And the solution I'm mentioning might not have even existed when it was asked), but I came across it when looking into how to do the same thing, and thought it would be useful to put in my findings for anyone else. I've discovered that if you check the box for **Run script only when installing** on the run script screen, then it will only run when you do an Archive. I guess since there isn't an "Install" option for iOS apps, Archive gets treated as the same thing, at least for this purpose.

Answer (score 2):

For people who have been searching for how to add a run script build phase, there is a simple step-by-step guide (with screenshots) at http://runscriptbuildphase.com. It shows both Xcode 4 and Xcode 3.

Answer (score 1):

Found it!

In the XCode Build System Guide look at Adding and Deleting Build Phases.

In your XCode project, under Targets in the Groups and Files pane you can see the Run Script... double click to edit, delete to delete.

// :)

Comment: where is the fabled "Xcode build system guide" I assume this is an apple document?